# Call BigQuery `queries` API with two statements and access all results

Tags: google-bigquery

I am currently calling the BigQuery REST API detailed here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query, in two separate calls with different SQL statements, imagine:

```
SELECT * FROM 'foo' WHERE x = 1;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM 'foo; WHERE y = 2;
```

I currently run these HTTP requests in parallel, but would prefer to make one call to BigQuery. However, I cannot access all results if I combine these statements into a single call, a la:

```
SELECT * FROM 'foo' WHERE x = 1;
SELECT * FROM 'foo; WHERE y = 2;
```

In this case, the HTTP API only return the last statement's results.

Anyway around this?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: The data populates an analytics chart with two reports. The data source is the same BQ table the aggregation and group-by's are completely different in the two queries. The two queries above are silly examples.

Answer (score 0):

You don't document if you're using a specific language, but this example from python may help: [Can 2 result sets be viewed from bigquery.client.query()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62144039/can-2-result-sets-be-viewed-from-bigquery-client-query/62145435#62145435)

The TL;DR - when running a query with multiple statements, each statement is run as it's own (sub)job.  You need to traverse the set of jobs via `jobs.list` and access the results from each.

Comment: Sorry - I probably could have made it clearer but we're using the HTTP API directly (from CloudFlare Workers which don't support the google NPM libs).

Comment: Then yeah, use [jobs.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list) with parent job ID filter set to list the child jobs, and then [jobs.getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults) to iterate the results within each child job.  The numChildJobs in the query stats of the first job will tell you if there's any child jobs to traverse.